How to start a unrestricted hartree fock (UHF) calculation with a custom guess in PySCF?
At first I want to do a UHF calculation of Li$_2$ dimer with spin=6 which shall give a sequence of $\sigma_{1s} \sigma^*_{1s} \sigma_{2s} \pi_{2p_x} \pi_{2p_y} \pi_{2p_z}$ (ordering might be wrong) MOs and then from that calculation I want to use $\sigma_{1s} \sigma^*_{1s} \sigma_{2s} \pi_{2p_x}$ MOs as an initial guess to run a He$_2$ dimer spin=4 UHF calculation in PySCF. Is it possible to cherry pick the MOs like this and run the calculation? If yes please tell me the recipe of how should I do it?
note: I want to compute total electronic energy
